# Troubleshooting "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" when require()ing twilio-lib.php

Tags: php, twilio

I have downloaded [the Twilio PHP library](http://www.twilio.com/api/) but I am getting an error when I try to include the library in my code.

Below is the error I get:

> Warning: require(twilio-lib.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /websites-dev/dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com/testing.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'twilio-lib.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /websites-dev/dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com/testing.php on line 11

Comment: Uhm, where did you save the file when downloading?

Answer (score 2):

Someone fudged up somewhere - there is no such `twilio-lib.php` file in [Twilio's PHP library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install).

Try removing the line in your downloaded PHP that looks exactly or similar to the following:

```
require "twilio-lib.php";
```

Comment: if i do that how is it going to use the commands that requrie the library?

Comment: **New Solution** Jeff, I just scoured the internet for the past two minutes and found the twilio-lib.php file. Please save a copy of it to your server in the same directory as the PHP file that requires it: http://labs.twilio.com/twimlets/source/twilio-lib.php

Comment: XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/testing.php
Line Number 7, Column 1:<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  FailUrl in <b>/websites-dev/dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com/testing.php</b> on line <b>66</b><br />
^

Comment: twilio-lib.php is the same as twilio.php found here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php I'll file a ticket to get that fixed in our downloads/examples. I thought we had got all of them.